# How to create quotes in accordance with oil prices?

Tags: integration

How to get the stock exchange oil price and integrate it in Salesforce (for a quote) ?

Comment: Welcome to the site Staif, please try to provide as much detail as possible when asking questions and explain exactly what you're stuck on. Open ended questions like this tend to generate discussion and aren't suited to the site; instead try to explain what research you've done so far and ask about a specific part of it.